# C: Why all elements of array are the same

Tags: c

Function rand_char is used to generate random letters that will be assigned to the string.

```
char rand_char(){
    char rand_ch;
    srand(time(NULL));
    rand_ch = rand() %26 +'A';
    return rand_ch;
}
for (j=0; j<7; j++){
    game->players[0].hand[j].letter = rand_char();
}
```

if I check printf("%c",game->players[0].hand[j].letter); all elements have the same letter. But they should have different random letters.

Comment: Also a duplicate of [`srand()` — why call it just once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move `srand(time(NULL));` out of `rand_char()`. `srand` should be done once before the `for` loop, not every time in `rand_char()`